# Python Dividing number by 99 and then checking if it is equal to number b par 2 digits

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, divide

I am trying to write a program that first of all checks if you can get from number a to number b by only swapping 2 digits. My below code is designed to start at 53150220288 and then check if it is possible to reach number 537163806382 by only changing 2 digits. So basically i am trying to only change 2 digits of the number 537163806382 so that the new numbers are multiples of 99. Then output them to a text file. I am writing this program to do it for me but it is actually for a maths competition.

```
f = open('Blank.txt', 'w')
a = 53150220288
b = 537163806382
b = str(b)
c = 0
while a <= 1000000000:
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i] == a[i]:
            c = c
        else:
            c = c + 1
    if c == 2:
        a = str(a)
        print(a, file=f)
    else:
        c = 0
        a = int(a)
        a = a + 99

f.close()
```

Problem with the above code is that it outputs absolutely nothing! I don't know why?

Comment: c is already an `int` you dont have to say `c = int(c)`

Comment: Thanks for the input @AnshumanDwibhashi but that still doesn't fix my problem..

Comment: `53150220288  < 1000000000` is False, your programs never enters that while loop.

Comment: When you switch two numbers, the difference is a multiple of 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program never enters the while loop:

```
a =       53150220288
while a <= 1000000000:
```

Answer (score 2):

The obvious reason is that your program doesn't enter the loop.

so do this:

```
a = 53150220288
while a <= 1000000000:
```